# li tag odd,even code not working when we use pagination

Tags: jquery, ajax, css, pagination

I have used this jquery script.I works fine for the page doesnot have pagination .For ex( i have an n numbers of li tags which is using this script for css purpose. on first page it will show only 10 articles and bottom of the page will have pagination when i click to view on second page the script will not work.)Is there anything need to change with this??

```
   <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $ ('ul.over-list li:even').addClass('even');
        $ ('ul.over-list li:odd').addClass('odd');
    });
   </script>
```

Comment: @PratikJoshi the problem is obvious when you realize which event is handled in posted JS and that OP uses AJAX and pagination.

Answer (score 1):

Elements loaded with AJAX appear after the user clicks the button with page number. This happens **after** document is ready and they are not affected by the handler of `ready` event.

You have two options:
1. Add callback to your AJAX request which will add `even` and `odd` classes to new elements on page.
2. Use `li:even` and `li:odd` selectors in your CSS instead of duplicating them with class.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. I want to use callback function into my script??.